# Adding GUI items from a series in Red Language

Tags: user-interface, red

I want to add GUI items from a series. I am trying following code but it does not work:

```
mylist: ["first" "second" "third" "fourth" ]

view[
    foreach i mylist [
        text i  ]]
```

The error is:

```
*** Script Error: VID - invalid syntax at: [foreach ll mylist]
*** Where: do
*** Stack: view layout cause-error
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that...

```
view [... what goes in here...]
```

...is a dialect, it is not regular code. It's a special dialect that has some evaluative qualities, but the normal rules don't always apply.

Don't forget that a dialect is just a block of values like anything else in Red. You can pre-build it as such:

```
view collect [
    foreach i mylist [
        keep 'text keep i
    ]
]
```

You can stick a `PROBE` between `VIEW` and `COLLECT` there to see what you're generating and `COLLECT/KEEP` gives you a lot of scope for tuning the values that end up in your view spec.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are mixing dialects.  You have a VID dialect inside the View block, but you're also using the DO dialect there as well which is not understood by View.

At least in Rebol you would add a `do` block as an initialization sequence inside the VID dialect eg.

```
view [
   VID dialect goes here ...
   do [ do dialect stuff that could initialize gui elements go here ]
]
```

Comment: Enclosing `foreach` part in `do[foreach ...]` does not help. A window appears but it has not visible text in it.